# Meta_query weird behaviour

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have a custom field called `date_from`. Dates are stored in the `yymmdd` format (eg 20131104). When I use a `meta_query` to find posts in a specific date range the query works as expected, but when I use a meta_query to find posts which have a date_from which is greater than the specified value it doesn't. That means; it doesn't return posts while I know for sure that it should. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

This is working:

```
$month = date('m');
$start_date = date( 'Y' . $month . '01' );
$end_date = date( 'Y' . $month . 't' );

$meta_query = array(
    'key'       => 'date_from',
    'value'     => array($start_date, $end_date),
    'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
    'type'      => 'DATE'
);

args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'events',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 20,
    'paged'         => $paged,
    'meta_query'        => array($meta_query),
    'meta_key'      => 'date_from',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

And this is not:

```
$today = date("Ymd");

$meta_query = array(
    'key'       => 'date_from',
    'value'     => $today,
    'compare'   => '>=',
    'type'      => 'DATE' // I've also tried type => 'NUMERIC'
);

args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'events',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 20,
    'paged'         => $paged,
    'meta_query'        => array($meta_query),
    'meta_key'      => 'date_from',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

And it does work when I use:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'events',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 20,
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'meta_key'          => 'date_from',
    'meta_value'        => $today,
    'meta_compare'      => '>',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
);
```

Why is that? I can't use `$meta_query = array(...)` to find posts which have a date greater than a specified value? Seems really odd because when I use exactly the same values directly in `$args` it does work.

Comment: Did you search for this? There are several Q&A's on here concerning (meta_)queries and dates.

Comment: Yes I did. Tried everything suggested and also read the codex on this. I'm specifically confused by the fact that the query which uses `BETWEEN` does work because that means it the problem isn't the date format. Next to that the exact same meta keys and values directly in `$args` work, but not in `$meta_query = array()`.

Comment: Is this a copy/paste problem: `args = array(` ?

Comment: @birgire Not only that. `$paged` is defined nowhere :P

Comment: It looks like you ain't got debugging activated. Please [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and file an [edit] so we can look at your error messages.

Comment: Oh, and then there's the problem with mixing `meta_query` and plain `meta_key` stuff. @joostvanhoof may want to take a look at `date_query` as well.

Comment: Also, perhaps consider using the `parse_request` or similar action to spew out the SQL, and test it using MySQLWorkbench or similar tool on your database. The SQL result may make it obvious what the issue is. It could be an incompatibility with how `Meta_Query` uses `DATE` comparison and `>=` in tandum.

Comment: @EricHolmes:  `$query = new WP_Query($args); printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', $query->request );` might be useful in this case ...

Comment: @kaiser: the doctor orders in this case: 1 large teaspoon of `WP_DEBUG` every day for 2 weeks ;-)

Comment: @birgire; not a copy/paste problem :-). @kaiser: I've left out $paged since it wasn't relevant to the problem and I have debugging enabled. But I have to confess something here (what's the emoticon for shame?); $meta_query was built based on input from a form. Somewhere I've mixed up an if statement which builds the $meta_query and now it's working. Oops! Sorry guys but thanks a lot of the useful input! I'll make sure I'll describe my questions better in the future.

Comment: @joostvanhoof No problem. Sometimes you need to just write things down to get aware of the issues. Two thirds of all questions I ever wanted to write have been solved during writing and have never been asked :)